# IntelliJ SQLite permission denied on Android Lollipop, worked before

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, intellij-idea

I updated Nexus 7 with Android Lollipop and now i can't access SQLite db from IntelliJ IDEA 14. Everything was working fine before Lollipop update, even though Android wasn't rooted i could access db from IntelliJ (but not pull it via ADB).
The error i am getting when i try to connect is:

```
Data Source Synchronization Error
Cannot synchronize 'SQLite': run-as: exec failed for /data/local/tmp/intellij_native_tools/get_modification_time Error:Permission denied
```

I am aware that SQLite was updated in lollipop from 3.7 to 3.8. What could cause this kind of error? Wrong DB creation, old DB drivers, something else?

Comment: Same issue here (idea 14.2 / Ubuntu 14.4.64 / Lollipop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`adb root` doesn't resolve anything, there's numerous issues depending on environment. Here's how I got it working on emulator where I spend a lot of my development time.

First we need to resolve the error `only position independent executables (PIE) are supported` with the binary.

get the source of android ultimate plugin tool:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea
cd idea/android/ultimate/get_modification_time/jni
```

Apply the following patch:

```
diff --git a/android/ultimate/get_modification_time/jni/Application.mk b/android/ultimate/get_modification_time/jni/Application.mk
index a252a72..bdf815d 100644
--- a/android/ultimate/get_modification_time/jni/Application.mk
+++ b/android/ultimate/get_modification_time/jni/Application.mk
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 APP_ABI := all
+APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

You'll need to setup a recent version of NDK to build, I had ndk-r10d installed already.

```
# ndk-r10d
ndk-build
cd ..
cp -R libs native_tools
# update the intellij plugin with whatever arch you plan to use
# adjust the path here to where your copy of IntelliJ is located
zip -u ~/local/apps/idea/plugins/android/lib/android-ultimate.jar native_tools/*/get_modification_time
```

Note that you need to update the path in that last line to point to your local IntelliJ installation. For example, on MacOS, it'll be:

```
zip -u /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/android-ultimate.jar native_tools/*/get_modification_time
```

Restart IntelliJ.

Next, we'll be replacing `/system/bin/run-as` on the emulator. Create the following script locally and name it `run-as`.

```
#! /system/bin/sh
INTELLIJ_NATIVE="/data/local/tmp/intellij_native_tools/get_modification_time"
if [ "$2" = "$INTELLIJ_NATIVE" ]; then
        cd /data/local/tmp/intellij_native_tools
        ./get_modification_time "$3"
else
        /system/bin/run-as.org "$@"
fi
```

Start the emulator. After it has booted, update it.

```
# update run-as after start
adb shell mount -o remount,rw /system
adb shell mv /system/bin/run-as /system/bin/run-as.org
adb push ./run-as /system/bin/run-as
```

Now you can synchronize to your heart's content.

Note, you may also want to follow progress on the bug upstream which just had priority bumped after posting this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137606

Comment: Thanks, i didn't try this as i am on kitkat when i need access to SQLite because this seems like too much work and i am hoping it will be fixed in 5.1. 
If it doesn't get fixed in new lollipop i'll try this, but i'll accept this as answer :)

Comment: To be clear, it's not a problem specific to 5.0, its a tooling issue with the android ultimate plugin and when the plugin is fixed, 5.+ will just work. I agree though, it's quite a lot to get it working but if you plan on a long debug session on 5.0, and already have the environment setup to do the above, it's worth the little extra time up-front to get it going. Otherwise, go old fashion and manually push/pull the sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rooted device try command

```
adb root
```

After it IDEA synhronization is successfull.

Comment: "adb root" cannot run root in production builds. So i did adb shell / su. But i am getting the same permission denied error.
What does intellij actuality put inside my android to be able to read db?

Comment: Agree, this should totally work without having to root the device.